# Serializing a Fingerprint template in java (DigitalPersona u.r.u 4500)

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, fingerprint, persona

I'm currently working with DigitalPersona u.are.u 4500 using One touch SDK

I used this code to create a template to be save in database

```
DPFPFeatureSet features = extractFeatures(sample, DPFPDataPurpose.DATA_PURPOSE_ENROLLMENT);
    // Check quality of the sample and add to enroller if it's good
    if (features != null) {
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("The fingerprint feature set was created.");
                    enroller.addFeatures(features);     // Add feature set to template.

                }
```

then I put this in  insert statement `enroller.getTemplate.Serialize()`                   to save the template in mysql with a datatype of blob

the problem is when I retrieve and deserialize the template and compare to my featureset it doesn't match and I found out that the format being saved to template is way too diff than I expected.

this is the value I get from database: 5b4240333532366366 (I get this value through netbeans IDE)

Is there a code I must use to save a proper format of template in my database

Comment: Why not just save the template without serializing? The template will not be more than 1KB.

Comment: @lmiguelmh how ? have you done it before ? can you provide a little more info ?

Comment: Yes, the SDK have methods to generate ISO or ANSI templates. This templates dont weight more than 500 bytes.